# Cannot assign view permission for GA360 to Google Groups

Tags: google-groups, google-analytics

When assigning permission to Google Groups, an error "Failed to register users" shows up. Not sure what is wrong behind the scene.

As we do want to centralize our user management using solely Google Identity (https://groups.google.com/). Is there a way to do it?

Thank you,